# Is there equivalent of RxJava Completable in project reactor?

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor

I don't want to return anything from my Mono, just wait for it to complete without errors. In RxJava I would use Completable, but what is recommended way of doing it in Project-Reactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Project Reactor team [recommends using `Mono<Void>`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1268#issuecomment-400954184) in situations where you use a `Completable` in RxJava. They also provide [an adapter](https://projectreactor.io/docs/adapter/release/api/reactor/adapter/rxjava/RxJava2Adapter.html#completableToMono-io.reactivex.Completable-) that turns a `Completable` into a `Mono<Void>` if you need to integrate both libraries together.